# Special Grid Header styles for sorting header (yii2)

Tags: grid, yii2

I want to put some additional HTML to the sorting column in Grid:

```
<th>Simple column</th>
<th>Column with sorting <span class="asc"></span></th>
```

How i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `encodeLabel` property like that:

```
....
            [                
                'label' => 'Your label <span class="asc"></span>',
                'encodeLabel' => false,
                'attribute' => 'description', // your field            
            ],
.....
```

See [doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-datacolumn.html#$encodeLabel-detail) and you must use Yii 2.0.1 version.